# CSS - white space control of slashes vs. spaces

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I've got some text coming in that I don't have control over but want to control the display of.

i.e. my code: `<div>{{ incoming_text }}</div>`

It's also in an environment where I can't do anything fancy with `incoming_text` (like string substitution/replacement).

When the text is as follows 'trapped/in difficulty/cornered (participle)', the wrapping (at narrow widths) goes as follows:

```
trapped/in
difficulty/cornered
(participle)
```

Is there a way to control this so that the text instead wraps:

```
trapped/
in difficulty/
cornered
(participle)
```

The problem is that the word wrap between 'in' and 'difficulty' actually confuses the meaning of that, i.e. it needs to be kept together.

---

So something like the following would also be acceptable:

```
trapped/in difficu-
lty/cornered (part-
iciple)
```

Comment: The last of your examples should be possible by appling `hyphens: auto`, I suppose

Comment: I've just tried that but I can't seem to get it working (have tried along with `text-align: justify`).  It still prefers to break on a space.

Comment: Cannot use entity `&nbsp;` (a non breaking space)?

Comment: yes, I imagine this would solve it, however I don't have any control over the input text

Answer (score 1):

> It's also in an environment where I can't do anything fancy with
>   incoming_text (like string substitution/replacement).

Absent this condition you can replace `/` with `<span class="separator">/<span>` using javascript.

Then you can add an `::after` pseudo-element which introduces a newline:

```
.separator::after {
  content: '\00000a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

But I'm pretty sure it's not possible to use a single character `/` as a CSS Selector, without including it in a `<span>` element first.

I've looked on **MDN** at newer pseudo-classes like `:where` and `:is` but nothing - even in the latest CSS - appears to give access to a text node.

Comment: Yes, but even if I could do this, wouldn't this always add a break after a slash?  I don't want a break if it would otherwise all fit on the same line.

Comment: Agreed. It's a conundrum. I'm really sorry I couldn't help more.